# Fluent mapping fails with "Could not determine type..." exception.

Tags: string, nhibernate, mapping, fluent, identifier

In my project I have this mapping:

```
public virtual string LicensePlate { get; set; }

public VehicleMap()
{
    Table("VEHICLE");

    Id(x => x.LicensePlate, "LICENSE_PLATE");
    ...
}
```

And when I try to run the app an MappingException is generated, specifying:

```
    Could not determine type for: nononono.Vehicle, nononono.DataAccess, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null, for columns: NHibernate.Mapping.Column(LICENSE_PLATE)
```

Could someone point me where I am doing it wrong?

I´ve tried setting the `Id` to `.NotNullable`, `.GeneratedBy.Assigned()` and none helped.

Comment: can you change the id to something else? I suspect the error is somehwere else and excluding this would show that

Comment: Can you post your `Vehicle.cs` file?

Comment: Thanks @rae1n, the error was in the  `Vehicle.cs` file.

Answer (score 2):

Solved the problem, it was on another class that is using the entity incorrectly.

Instead of

```
    public virtual Vehicle VehicleLicensePlate{ get; set; }
```

I changed to

```
    public virtual string VehicleLicensePlate{ get; set; }
```

Comment: I found very helpful, the fact that error for this id column is caused by some other class referencing this class incorrectly. Meaning that this class does not have errors.